# How can I organize tests operating on a range of similar inputs?

Tags: php, phpunit

Given a set of test data files

- `test001.txt`
- `test002.txt`
- etc.

and expected results data files

- `expected001.txt`
- `expected002.txt`
- etc.

I am using `phpunit` to test the data processing functionality:

```
public function test001()
{
    $fn = "test001.txt";
    $data = file_get_contents($fn);

    // code to perform the test, and create $processedData from  $data

    $fn = "expected001.txt";
    $expestedData = file_get_contents($fn);

    $this->assertEquals($expestedData, $processedData);
}
```

The process code is exactly the same for all pairs of test data files and corresponding result data files.

Therefore, to apply the test on all the files I can make a loop:

```
public function test001to213()
{
    for ($k = 0; $k < 213; $k++) {
        $fn = "test".sprintf('%03d', $k).".txt";
        $data = file_get_contents($fn);

        // data process code to create $processedData from $data

        $fn = "expected".sprintf('%03d', $k).".txt";
        $expectedData = file_get_contents($fn);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedData, $processedData);
    }
}
```

However, this way I have 213 assertions in one test, and I loose the following benefits:

1. I cannot know what tests numbers failed/passed, since the test stops for first failed assertion.
2. On the second execution, I cannot run only the failed tests.
3. I cannot choose a specific test number x - to run in debug mode

Before adding more code to get this benefits, is there a better solution?
What `phpunit` features can help in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a data provider instead:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider providerFilenames
 *
 * @param string $testFilename
 * @param string $expectedFilename
 */
public function testContent($testFilename, $expectedFilename)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($testFilename);

    // code to perform the test, and create $processedData from  $data
    $processedData = '';

    $expectedData = file_get_contents($expectedFilename);

    $this->assertEquals($expectedData, $processedData);
}

/**
 * @return \Generator
 */
public function providerFilenames()
{
    for ($key = 0; $key < 213; ++$key) {
        $testFilename = sprintf(
            'test%03d.txt',
            $key
        );

        $expectedFilename = sprintf(
            'expected%03d.txt',
            $key
        );

        /**
         * by yielding with a name here, it's easier to tell which set failed
         */
        $name = sprintf(
            'this is set %03d',
            $key
        );

        yield $name => [
            $testFilename,
            $expectedFilename ,
        ];
    }
}
```

If you can't use generators yet, adjust the data provider to:

```
/**
 * @return \Generator
 */
public function providerFilenames()
{
    $keys = range(0, 213);

    $names = array_map(function ($key) {
        return sprintf(
            'this is set %03d',
            $key
        );
    }, $keys);

    $data = array_combine(
        $names,
        $keys
    );

    return array_map(function ($key) {
        $testFilename = sprintf(
            'test%03d.txt',
            $key
        );

        $expectedFilename = sprintf(
            'expected%03d.txt',
            $key
        );

        return [
            $testFilename,
            $expectedFilename
        ];
    }, $data);
}
```

For reference, see:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php